# Instance on every 10th node of curve

Tags: node-editor, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I try to put an instance on every 10th (8th, 6th etc.) point (vertex) of the curve.
My nodes are
[image: Nodes geometry]

But this doesn't work. I have the instances on every point of the curve.
Their number does not depend on the number by which I divide the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using modulo in selection input:

[image]

Also note that I've used Index as input instead of *Spline parameter*. Your spline is converted to mesh by *Curve to Mesh* node, *Spline parameter* doesn't work with meshes.

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: @IgorYukhimenko Of course Crantisz's solution works, but you would have to apply the node `Instance on Points` to the curve, and not to the mesh you created with `Curve to Mesh` before.

Comment: I've used *Index* as input instead of *Spline parameter*. Your spline is converted to mesh by *Curve to Mesh* node, *Spline parameter* doesn't work with meshes.

Comment: @quellenform, thank. It's work now